# Google script custom trigger onEdit(e) issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting error in line 29. But the same code works when pasted in another sheet. Separate trigger is used. Edit-> Current project's trigger.

```
var Team_email='abc@gmail.com'; 

function TriggerOnEdit(e)
{
  Logger.log("stg1");
  sendEmailOnassigned(e);
 }

function showMessageOnApproval(e)
{
  var edited_row = checkStatusIsAssigned(e);
  if(edited_row > 0)
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Row # "+edited_row+" approved!");
  }
}

function showMessageOnUpdate(e)
{
  var range = e.range;

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("range updated " +   range.getA1Notation());  
}

function checkStatusIsAssigned(e)
{
  Logger.log("stg3");
  var range = e.range;

  if(range.getColumn() <= 12 && 
     range.getLastColumn() >=12 )
  {
    var edited_row = range.getRow();

    var status = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(edited_row,11).getValue();
    if(status == 'Assigned')
    {
      return edited_row;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

function sendEmailOnassigned(e)
{
  Logger.log("stg2");
  var approved_row = checkStatusIsAssigned(e);

  if(approved_row <= 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  Logger.log("stg4");
  sendEmailByRow(approved_row);
}

function sendEmailByRow(row)
{
  Logger.log("stg5");
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1,row,13).getValues();
  var row_values = values[0];

  var mail = composeAssignedEmail(row_values);

  MailApp.sendEmail(Team_email,mail.subject,mail.message);

  var Requester_email = composeRequesterEmail(row_values);

  MailApp.sendEmail(Requester_email.email,Requester_email.subject,Requester_email.message);
}



function composeAssignedEmail(row_values)
{
  Logger.log("stg6");
  var Request_Number = row_values[1];

  var email = row_values[2];

  var Project_Name = row_values[4];

  var Nature_Of_Work = row_values[5];

  var Quantity = row_values[6];

  var Estimated_Hours  = row_values[7];

  var Name  = row_values[12];


  var message = "Hello Requester, \n  "+" \n The following Resource "+ Name ;

  var subject = "Request_Number - " + Request_Number ;

  return({message:message,subject:subject});
}


function composeRequesterEmail(row_values)
{
  Logger.log("stg7");


  var Request_Number = row_values[1];

  var email = row_values[2] ;

  var Project_Name = row_values[4];

  var Nature_Of_Work = row_values[5];

  var Quantity = row_values[6];

  var Estimated_Hours  = row_values[7];

  var Name  = row_values[12];


  var message = "Hello Requester, \n  "+" \n The following Resource "+ Name;


  var subject = "Request_Number - " + Request_Number;



  return({message:message,subject:subject, email:email });
}
```

Please tell me the error where is the mistake.

We can not use debug function to understand the mistake. because trigger is on edit.

Also when we use 'e' what are the information do we feed the function?

How to correct this?

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Can you provide a sample sheet on which your code does not work?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 29, file "Assign")

Comment: I understand that if since trigger is on Edit. I should not run the function manually. But even on performing edit function in sheet. I dont get mail

Comment: Are you running your code manually by pressing the "Play" button? e.range only works when the script is run automatically by the trigger, not when testing manually. If your script runs correctly on trigger but you do not get an email - it means that the specified conditions are not fulfilled. Hard to say without seeing your sheet.